# Auto form field update based on 2 specific table entries

Tags: ms-access

I'm still new to access and although I understand the basics (tables, queries, forms, VBA and now some SQL) this is probably a simple solution but I need a field on a form to display a specific field entry based on 2 criteria automatically, preferably without running an update query.

I tried the code below in the field however I'm fairly certain it is completely wrong for what I am needing to do.

```
=IIf([Admin - update Log].[Date Live]>="") AND ([Admin - update Log].[Version]>="")
```

Basically the 'Home' form needs to automatically display the latest 'Version' number based on the latest 'Date Live'. *Probably simple to anyone who has been using access/sql for over a month.*

Comment: Since your version numbers are of equal length & prefixed with leading zeroes, `DMax` should be able to correctly retrieve the latest version even by sorting by the ASCII character code at each position. Are you able to post some sample data?

Comment: Unfortunately the 'version' field is actually a _text_ field which means the DMax won't work and I would have to create a custom function as advised by @Gustav but an example of what should be displayed is [Here](https://imgur.com/NyFUssh) based on this image the version number that should be displayed on the home form is 01.67.013

Comment: As noted, since your version numbers follow a consistent length with leading zeros, `DMax` will work and using a database populated with your sample data, Gustav's sample code works fine for me.

Comment: You are completely correct, I have it working now, i just needed to amend the control source properly (rookie mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find the latest *Date Live* with this expression:

```
=DMax("[Date Live]","[Admin - update Log]")
```

then you can use this to find the latest *Version*:

```
=DMax("[Version]","[Admin - update Log]","[Date Live] = DMax('[Date Live]','[Admin - update Log]')")
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I tried that within the expression builder and it still returned the first value. I amended it slightly to add the 'onload' function in case it was a simple form required update issue but that failed also.


=OnLoad(DMax("[Version]","[Admin - update Log]","[Date Live] = DMax('[Date Live]','[Admin - update Log]')"))


Seems this field is adamant it only wants to display the first record for version

Comment: Can't tell, sorry, but if the "first" value is the newest, it is OK. But it is not quite clear what you are after, an there is no `OnLoad` to use.

Comment: Sorry, should have phrased that in access terminology, the error I'm getting is even with the expression added the first field for version (01.01.001) is displayed, the correct number for example currently is (01.02.027) which is the 37th/42nd field for 'Version'. It would only take me a few seconds to update manually if I was using a label however I was preferring an automation in case updating the label slips my mind.

Comment: Oh, but those version numbers are _text_. It will require a custom function to sort these as you probably expect: part one (01) first, then part two, and finally part three (027).

Comment: That makes sense, think i'll stick to the manual label update for the time being until I get more confident with Access. Thanks for all the help.